# Vibrating object on optical table

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, material-science, vibrations, metals

Wikipedia says this about [optical tables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_table):

> Many optical systems require that vibration of optical elements be kept small. As a result, optical tables are typically very heavy and incorporate vibration isolation and damping features in their structure. Many use pneumatic isolators that act as mechanical low-pass filters, reducing the ability of vibrations in the floor to cause vibrations in the tabletop.

So if an object lies on the optical table and the floor is vibrating, then the object will not be affected by that.

However, what happens when we put a metal sphere on the optical table and strike it? Normally, such an object would vibrate and produce a clear sound pitch which gradually becomes weaker. This would continue for many seconds. But the optical table is made of damping materials. Would the metal sphere produce any sound at all? And will this sound continue just as long as on any other table? Or will it die out much quicker?

Comment: If the object is producing a clear sound pitch then it is not well connected to anything else, including the table. While I can't say I've exhaustively tested, optics benches don't behave particularly differently to sound than regular tables.

Comment: If you want to try an experiment at home, garages often have a concrete floor. That would act much like a granite optical bench. Or try the sidewalk.